# 404 редирект со страниц "/?..."

Tags: .htaccess, modx, redirect, редирект

Подскажите как сделать 404 редирект со страниц типа mysite.ru/? mysite.ru/?dsfds
именно с конструкцией "/?..", так начинается get запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
# если в запросе есть /?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?
# то тогда 404 редирект
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```